# swift #pragma replacement to stub out code in production vs dev (ie #if TEST_CODE == 1)?

Tags: ios, swift, pragma

I have test code that I use for GPS testing of my app that I want
to stub out entirely so that its not even compiled into the binary.
Its a simple way to turn on/off testing throughout the codebase for
various things I wish to test.

in Objective-C I would do:

```
#define TEST_CODE == 1
```

and use it like this for example:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

#if TEST_CODE == 1
    addressTextField.text = @"My Real Address";
#endif
    ...
}
```

Since binaries can be searched with things like the 'strings' command,
I don't want any of my test stuff to reach production, however AFAIK
there is no way to do that in swift.

Does anyone have any solutions that would do this?

It seems like a deficiency of swift not to have some type of mechanism
to do so.  I can't be the only one who uses #pragma's in this way.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in Swift is conditional compilation.

You can set your conditional flag as `-DTEST_CODE` in the `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` build setting for your Debug configuration. Then, you can refer to it from Swift files as such:

```
#if TEST_CODE
   // conditionally do something
#endif
```

Note that there is no support for flag values, so you cannot pass the value 1.

For more information: [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 4): Preprocessor Directives](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID31)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Original source of the information [kitefaster site](https://kitefaster.com/2016/01/23/how-to-specify-debug-and-release-flags-in-xcode-with-swift/)